# How does thin film increase the efficiency of solar panels?

Tags: reflection, interference

The idea is that a thin-film on solar panels will cause destructive interference thus lowering the amount of reflected light and causing more light to be absorbed by the panel. However I do not understand why it is so.

Consider an incident ray hitting the thin-film covering the panel. Some of the energy will be reflected and some will be transmitted.
Some of the transmitted rays energy will then be reflected at the panel and some will be absorbed and turned into electricity. The reflected ray from the panel will then interfer with the reflected ray from the thin-film.
It is stated that if there is destructive interference between these rays, it would mean that the panel absorbed more energy?

How can something that happens with the ray **after** the interaction between thin-film and panel, affect how much energy was absorbed?

Answer (score 0):

[Antireflection coatings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-reflective_coating) are very common in optics. Forget rays, you have to think in terms of waves here. The interference between the first and second reflections cancels the outgoing reflected wave. What does that mean? Energy is conserved. Interference doesn't cause it to disappear: it goes somewhere else. In this case, the only place it can go is into the transmitted wave, into the panel.